# MySQL generate all possible combinations from numbers with a certain length

Tags: mysql, combinations, permutation

how to generate all possible combinations from numbers in a MySql table with a certain length? For example 8 numbers.

Only with MySql not together with php.

My table "numbers" contains:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I want now to let create all possible combinations in "numbers1".

Like:

```
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
```

Comment: Why not use a loop for this?

Comment: I search the best & fastest way ;-) How to do it best with loop?

Comment: I guess the fastest way would be, to set an identity seed column and Insert as much rows as you need in a while loop. The downside on this would be the missing left padding zeros, but you can get those with a fitting select statement.

Comment: How is a single column a permutation - would expect something like 0,1 0,2 0,3 etc

Comment: @P.Salmon I changed it in Question

Comment: The best and fastest way is to not use sql

Comment: Combination and permutation are synonyms so my comment remains.

Comment: @Strawberry What a comment ;-) but I want to have it in mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon Well, permutations are a subset of combinations.

Comment: @Strawberry - isn't the difference simply that ordering/sequencing is important in permutations but not in combinations and isn't the op simply after a cartesian product (with added bits)?

Comment: Yes, I think so - although in this instance, the OP is *(I think)* simply after all numbers from 1 to 99999999 - as evidenced by all the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

if the length is fixed it is quite simple, so you could do something like this

```
DECLARE @number TABLE (num NVARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @number
VALUES ('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')

SELECT n1.num + n2.num + n3.num + n4.num
FROM @number n1, @number n2, @number n3, @number n4
```

if the number is variable you could either build the sql-command and execute it using `sp_execute @cmd` or you can create a table-value-function for it.

Edit: I just overread the "mysql"-part. the solution above is coded in TSQL (using MS SqlServer). I am not completely sure, but the only thing you have to change should be the declaration of the variable.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE @number (num NVARCHAR(1))
```

And if I am not mistaken instead of using `sp_execute`to execute a command you can use something like

```
PREPARE cmd FROM 'SELECT ...'
EXECUTE cmd
```

Comment: Lots of things in this solution are not appropriate to mysql

Comment: Yes I also think so.

Comment: added some more info concerning the concrete mysql implementation

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a cartesian product but I don't get why you want a single column in your output but anyway

```
select distinct case when u1.id >= u.id then u.id else u1.id end umin,
         case when u1.id < u.id then u.id else u1.id end umax
from users u cross join users u1
where u1.id <> u.id
order by umin,umax
```

The cross join creates the cartesian product the where clause drops those where the combination/permuatation results in the same value eg 1,1 2,2 etc and the distinct dedupes
So given this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id  from users;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
| 10 |
| 12 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 20 |
+----+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query results in

```
+------+------+
| umin | umax |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    6 |
|    1 |    7 |
|    1 |    8 |
|    1 |   10 |
|    1 |   12 |
|    1 |   14 |
|    1 |   15 |
|    1 |   16 |
|    1 |   17 |
|    1 |   18 |
|    1 |   19 |
|    1 |   20 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    6 |
|    2 |    7 |
|    2 |    8 |
|    2 |   10 |
|    2 |   12 |
|    2 |   14 |
|    2 |   15 |
|    2 |   16 |
|    2 |   17 |
|    2 |   18 |
|    2 |   19 |
|    2 |   20 |
|    3 |    6 |
|    3 |    7 |
|    3 |    8 |
|    3 |   10 |
|    3 |   12 |
|    3 |   14 |
|    3 |   15 |
|    3 |   16 |
|    3 |   17 |
|    3 |   18 |
|    3 |   19 |
|    3 |   20 |
|    6 |    7 |
|    6 |    8 |
|    6 |   10 |
|    6 |   12 |
|    6 |   14 |
|    6 |   15 |
|    6 |   16 |
|    6 |   17 |
|    6 |   18 |
|    6 |   19 |
|    6 |   20 |
|    7 |    8 |
|    7 |   10 |
|    7 |   12 |
|    7 |   14 |
|    7 |   15 |
|    7 |   16 |
|    7 |   17 |
|    7 |   18 |
|    7 |   19 |
|    7 |   20 |
|    8 |   10 |
|    8 |   12 |
|    8 |   14 |
|    8 |   15 |
|    8 |   16 |
|    8 |   17 |
|    8 |   18 |
|    8 |   19 |
|    8 |   20 |
|   10 |   12 |
|   10 |   14 |
|   10 |   15 |
|   10 |   16 |
|   10 |   17 |
|   10 |   18 |
|   10 |   19 |
|   10 |   20 |
|   12 |   14 |
|   12 |   15 |
|   12 |   16 |
|   12 |   17 |
|   12 |   18 |
|   12 |   19 |
|   12 |   20 |
|   14 |   15 |
|   14 |   16 |
|   14 |   17 |
|   14 |   18 |
|   14 |   19 |
|   14 |   20 |
|   15 |   16 |
|   15 |   17 |
|   15 |   18 |
|   15 |   19 |
|   15 |   20 |
|   16 |   17 |
|   16 |   18 |
|   16 |   19 |
|   16 |   20 |
|   17 |   18 |
|   17 |   19 |
|   17 |   20 |
|   18 |   19 |
|   18 |   20 |
|   19 |   20 |
+------+------+
105 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```